How to get my unread user notifications via the API?
I have thousands of new-video notifications on YouTube. I'm a crazy power user, and I want to (at least) look at all of them, preferably save them for later in a big list (like exporting bookmarks).
How can I get my unread notifications (as an end-user) using the API?
There don't seem to be any extensions for this, and I don't want to click on the bell, lest the page load "only" a few hundred videos before some loading-error hits. (This has happened to me at least once on some website, although I'm not sure if it was YouTube or not.)

https://codeberg.org/Benjamin_Loison/youtube_push_notifications/src/commit/a68468adbc76fd6c095901c59dcefe053ef3b57b/subscribe_callback.php#L128-L162 retrieves the first page of entries.

Hmmm, not sure how I would get that to scale, since (if I'm reading the cookies right (which I'm probably not, since I've never written PHP)) the cookie codes are "1PSID".

I do not understand your issue concerning scaling and the cookies.

Note that concerning getting following pages https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/d61488fbe0becf6d2a6ebc97761e5b87a8facd3f/tools/minimizeCURL.py and https://github.com/menmob/innertube-documentation/issues/1#issuecomment-1688923923 may help you.

More broadly, I don't know how to change that code to get more pages of data.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Following my comments the following works fine to retrieve only the last 275 notifications.
import requests
import time
import hashlib
import json

currentTime = int(time.time())
__Secure_1PSIDTS = 'sidts-CENSORED'
__Secure_1PSID = 'CENSORED'
__Secure_1PAPISID = 'CENSORED'

SAPISIDHASH = f'{currentTime}_' + hashlib.sha1(f'{currentTime} {__Secure_1PAPISID} https://www.youtube.com'.encode('ascii')).digest().hex()

cookies = {
    '__Secure-1PSIDTS': __Secure_1PSIDTS,
    '__Secure-1PSID': __Secure_1PSID,
    '__Secure-1PAPISID': __Secure_1PAPISID,
}


headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://www.youtube.com',
    'Authorization': f'SAPISIDHASH {SAPISIDHASH}',
}

json_data = {
    'context': {
        'client': {
            'clientName': 'WEB',
            'clientVersion': '2.20240814.00.00',
        },
    },
    'browseId': 'FEnotifications_inbox',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
items = response.json()['onResponseReceivedEndpoints'][0]['openPopupAction']['popup']['multiPageMenuRenderer']['sections'][0]['multiPageMenuNotificationSectionRenderer']['items']
allItems = []

while True:
    allItems += items
    for item in items:
        if 'notificationRenderer' in item:
            #print(json.dumps(item, indent = 4))
            notificationRenderer = item['notificationRenderer']
            print(notificationRenderer['shortMessage']['simpleText'])
            print(notificationRenderer['notificationId'])
            print()
    if not 'continuationItemRenderer' in item:
        break
    json_data['continuation'] = item['continuationItemRenderer']['continuationEndpoint']['continuationCommand']['token']
    items = requests.post('https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/browse', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data).json()['onResponseReceivedEndpoints'][0]['appendContinuationItemsAction']['continuationItems']
    
print(len(allItems))

Notes about how this algorithm was established are available at https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/297.
